# How to load datasets on google collab such that they remain whenever I open my notebook?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, dataset, jupyter

Google collab always shows that file will be unloaded when runtime finishes. Why?

I had to present a collab notebook in class and as soon as I opened the page everything was vanished. It was a large dataset so it took quite a few minutes to load it again.

Answer (score 0):

Collab starts with an empty computer every time, you can upload your dataset to your Google Drive and mount your Google Drive partition from your Collab notebook like this:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

On the left, a tree with all your Google Drive files will appear, and you can use them in your Collab, just right-click and copy the path and paste it into your notebook.

If you want a persistent computer, you will have to pay for it. As far as I know, Google Collab will keep the server running for 2 hours if you are in front of the computer. If no activity is detected on your side, Google will terminate the Collab notebook.